# Bootstrap - Align multiple select elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i am trying something very simple but can seem to figure it out. I have two `select` elements which I want to align horizontally with text in between. This is what I have: ( also on [codepen](http://codepen.io/isharief318/pen/KMwBKQ) )

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <select class="form-control input-sm">...</select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"> vs </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <select class="form-control input-sm">...</select>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I when I try to put a `vs (versus)` between them , if I use a `<p>` or `<div>` with no class defined the second `select` gets misaligned. If I wrap the `vs` in a `div class=col-xs-1` the gap is too big and doesnt look nice. What would be the best way to get a `vs` between the 2 `select` while keeping the alignment and not having a huge space between 2 elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Bootstrap looking at the CodePen. Bootstrap has a class for inline forms which you could use like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control"><option>Select option</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">vs</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control"><option>Select option</option></select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOYjBm

Comment: Great. Works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just tried with CSS

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 field">
  <select class="form-control input-sm">...</select>
  </div>
  <div><span>vs</span></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 field">
  <select class="form-control input-sm">...</select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
              div{
          display:inline;

        }

    .field{
      position:absolute;
    }

        span{
          position:relative;
          padding:0px;

        }
```

Comment: The `vs` is not displayed

Comment: Sorry i missed to provide the codepen url -Here you go:
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqgXGY